# what types of hops can be grown in india ( in rajasthan sami arid zone)

Tags: growing-hops

I want to grow hops in Rajasthan (India).  How do I get seeds for hops in India?  Are there any companies in India that can provide me with what's necessary to grow my own?

Comment: Plz tell me from where we get the hops rhizomes

Comment: These guys may be able to help you: https://nurserylive.com/buy-aromatic-plants-online-in-india/hops-plants-in-india

Comment: How do i get in touch with you Mr.Kitchloo i am interested in growing hops in india.

Comment: I also found this news story that may give some leads - https://www.oneindia.com/2009/10/20/hopscultivation-becoming-popular-with-himachalfarmers.html

Answer (score 3):

Hops grow from Rhizomes, essentially a stick/root that you put in the ground.  Make sure you  a string stretching 20 feet for the bines to grow up on.

Here is a site that ships them internationally.
http://www.freshops.com/order/international

Here is some tips for growing hops
 http://www.oregonhops.org/culture2.html

Cheers!

Comment: From freshhops website : International orders: we do not ship hop rhizomes to the Southern Hemisphere.  For other North American countries, there is a minimum order of 20 rhizomes, and different restrictions apply to different countries.  Please contact us with your request and country and we can get back to you with details for your country.

Comment: Luckily, India is a northern hemisphere :)

Answer (score 1):

Hops don't grow from seeds...they grow from rhizomes.  I recommend you talk to Hop Union about getting rhizomes.  The closer you are to the 45th parallel, the better they will grow.

Comment: Why the 45th parallel? They grow some excellent hop varieties in New Zealand and Australia.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that you have to be on the 45th.  But that's where the prime weather conditions will be found.  There's a reason almost all Us hop growing takes place around there.

Comment: Right, I found this after I made this comment http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/48th_parallel_north It just seems subjective to me, that is, I don't know if it is objectively true if they grow "better" or if it's more a matter of history, economics, etc. It's like saying the best wine in the world comes from California, or France, when great wine also comes from South America, Australia, etc. Hops are extremely resilient, and grow well in many regions. But they will have a different terroir just like grapes, tea, coffee, etc.

Comment: Denny!  He gave you the perfect out, all you would have had to say was, "I didn't specify north or [south](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/48th_parallel_south)!" NZ is quite close if you look at it that way! =)

Comment: Paul, I don't have links to cite, but I live in one of the prime hop growing areas and this is what the growers have always told me.  North or south doesn't matter.  If you;re within a certain distance of the 45th, the climate is closer to what hops prefer than if you're farther away.

Comment: As I understand it, the climate has a lot to do with it, but the bigger issue with latitutude is that the hop bines will only flower when there is a certain length of day -- and that length has to occur during an ideal window in the groing season. Moving away from the proper latitude will drastically reduce yields.

Answer (score 0):

Without much knowledge of the area, I'm going to suspect that your area's soil is going to be a very harsh, nutrient deprived environment to try and grow hops in.  You may want to look into growing hops through hydroponics.  I hear it isn't the easiest thing to pull off, as hops require a lot of nutrients, but there have been about as many success stories as there have been failures.  One thing is for certain, you likely have all the sun they'll ever need.

Answer (score 0):

Any type will grow as long as the soil is well amended and you water regularly (drip would be best).

I could not find any listings for homebrew shops in India.  I'd suggest finding a local agricultural university or coop and see if they can help you get rhizomes.

Answer (score 0):

Hops is a plant that can be grown in temperate climate and Rajesthan is not ideal location. Our research group has introduced hops cultivation in Lahaul (HP) and Leh Ladakh. If you want to cultivate it in these areas on partnership it is also possible or on buy back bases. 
Our laboratory is having complete technical know how in hops cultivation and post harvest processing.