# Are there any Indian Hop variety out there?

Tags: hops

I've heard that in the Himalayas a lot of hop varieties are grown. Is there a company(s) which produce and market hops in India?

Comment: Maybe he does: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/what-types-of-hops-can-be-grown-in-india-in-rajasthan-sami-arid-zone

Answer (score 1):

I could only find this [article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/chandigarh/Hops-turn-bitter-for-growers-in-Lahaul/articleshow/21589742.cms), I tell a lie, I have found a few more [this from 2009](http://www.oneindia.com/2009/10/20/hopscultivation-becoming-popular-with-himachalfarmers.html), you could maybe talk to the people who put up [this post last](https://medicinalplantinindia.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/hops-humulus-lupulus-sale-in-india.html) year advertising hop plants for sale.

Also maybe contact some of the Indian homebrew suppliers and see if they know anyone in the industry who can help. If you find out please provide an answer here, I would love to know, as homebrewing seems to be taking off in India and I expect more questions like this over time.

http://www.brewof.com/contact-us/

https://www.brewmart.in/contact-us/

http://www.diybrew.in/page/contact-us

Comment: Do Indian hops have distinctive varieties and flavors? If so, all it would take would be an enterprising exporter!  As an example, look at the quotas New Zealand has to apply to its hop exports - some NZ varieties are "too" popular for supply.